# Cache/Saved feature engineering result for reusing

Tags: feature-engineering, pandas

I use python pandas for transforming a csv with panda dataframe for feature engineering (e.g., handle missing values, extract feature etc.) and pass it to machine learning algorithm for handling.

Many times when I execute, it is to tune the algorithm. But now it always rerun the whole feature engineering codes make it very slow.

Is there a convenient way where if I modify feature engineering codes then it rerun the codes, and otherwise it will save the results, and reuse the results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a build system like [Gnu Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). You define your workflow as a directed acyclic graph (DAG) in a config file called the Makefile. When you run your workflow (building a "target"), the tool will populate a database with the last-modified dates of all the scripts that were run, their input dependencies, and the outputs that were built. If you rerun the workflow, the tool will check to see components have been modified and only run the the parts in your pipeline that need to be re-run.

[Here's a demonstration](https://github.com/dmarx/make_for_datascience) of a data science pipeline (made a bit complex by inclusion of some bells and whistles) managed by Gnu Make. The workhorse of that system is [this file](https://github.com/dmarx/make_for_datascience/blob/master/_footer.mak)